# How to resolve get request with axios in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to Axios, and I was trying to fetch data from an endpoint to use in React...

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/" });

export default function App() {
  api.get("/products").then(res => console.log(res.data));
  ...
}
```

Here is my endpoint code...

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

require("dotenv").config();

app.get("/products", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world!");
});

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

But instead of the `Hello world!` getting logged I am getting this error...

[image: null]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `cors` middleware in your backend server.

1. `npm install cors`
2. Enable all CORS requests

```
const express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

app.use(cors())
```

You can look for more information [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html). There are ways to configure your CORS as well.

To your another question, CRUD operations should be used in `useEffect` hook.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

    api.get("/products").then(res => console.log(res.data));

  }, [])

  ...
}
```

Comment: But can you provide why my code doesn't work and what cors is?

Comment: Also hello world is getting logged two times.

Comment: @EthanLal You will have to use `useEffect` hook in order to make any side effect. Meaning, any CURD requests should go in useEffect hook, that way you will not have re rendering effects.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer to reflect the `useEffect` hook usage.

Answer (score 1):

Hi look for this lib [Cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for express and you can use proxy in react project in your package.json instead of  axios.create()
like

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I'm going to accept the other answer because it showed me how to set up cors.